# Html from python to mysql

Tags: python, html, mysql

I am trying to insert html to mysql table using Python script. That way i want to edit article on my website, so the html has to be valid. This is an error i receive:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'n1'>Poniedziałek 30.08.2021r.</p>
<p>
        <b>6<sup>30</sup></b> za zmarłych ro...' at line 1
```

Perhaps there is a problem with special characters like `/n`, `/t` or `'`. Unfortunately I don't know how to solve that problem.

Here is part of code that I am trying to execute:

```
mycursor.execute("UPDATE `table_name` SET `col_name` = '" + doc_html + "' WHERE `table_name`.`id` = 1")
```

Beginning of `doc_html` (which is a string variable):

```
<html>\n<style>\n    p {\n        margin: 0em 0in;\n        font-size: 1em;\n        font-family: "Georgia", serif;\n        color: black;\n        text-align: left;\n    }\n\n    p.n1 {\n        margin: 1.5em 0in 0.25em;\n        font-size: 1.25em;\n        font-family: "Georgia", serif;\n        color: black;\n        font-weight: bold;\n        text-align: center;\n    }\n\n    ol.zbiorowa {\n        margin: 0;\n        font-family: "Georgia", serif;\n    }\n\n    br {\n        line-height: 50%;\n    }\n</style>\n\n\n\n<p class=\'n1\'>Poniedziałek 30.08.2021r.</p>\n<p>\n\t<b>6<sup>30</sup></b> za zmarłych rodziców chrzestnych: za + Janinę Sokołowską i za + Jana Cichonia<br/>\n\t<b>6<sup>30</sup></b> za
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use parameters

```
mycursor.execute("UPDATE `table_name` SET `col_name` = &s WHERE `table_name`.`id` = 1",(doc_html,))
```

Soy you can avoid to handle the characters that could cause that problem

Comment: Now I am gettin such message: `mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement`

Comment: Ok. As i am using `mysql.connector` I had to insert `%s` instead of `?`. Thanks a lot. It was a good lesson.

Comment: than you have a different query, that would ahppen when you ha`ve instead of `,(doc_html,)`  added more variables without adding ? to the query for example for id